# Enable user to edit CAD file in WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, pixelsense, autocad, cad

The resources for AutoCAD programming are one in a million; I have a little trouble trying to figure out how to do this. What I *actually* need (the entire workflow), is to allow the user to import a .DWG/.DXF file, display it onscreen, allow the user to make changes to the file, and then allow the user to save/share it with other users. You can say that this comes close to building another AutoCAD application, but I'm looking at a very basic implementation at this point of time.

I am aware of the many libraries available, but I'm not sure which one will be the best-fit for me. I'm looking forward to having an easy implementation (because I am not familiar with the vectors, coordinate geometry and all shitnitz), and it can employ the use of pay-to-use AutoCAD libraries, AutoCAD progaramming APIs, COM interop, ActiveX controls, *anything*. Whatever you think will work, I will give it a try.

If possible, I would like to further extend this question specifically to Microsoft PixelSense, because eventually that is what I will be developing for. However, no worries, just raise your suggestions, I'll give each and every one a try... thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298622/net-cad-component-that-can-read-write-dxf-dwg-files

Comment: That wheel has been invented: AutoCAD LT. Gotta be cheaper than trying to write it yourself on ODA or AutoCAD OEM (if they decide to license your app).

Answer (score 0):

For .dwg files look at www.opendesign.com.
Their Teigha libraries download has example projects.
They have support for C++, .NET and ActiveX.

I don't know of any libraries, including Autodesk's own API, that will get you an "easy implementation".

Comment: Even Autodesk's own API doesn't give an easy implementation..? Oh good God, now that is something new..

Comment: Autodesk OEM is pretty easy to implement but I don't think they will license an app that will undercut their own market for AutoCAD LT.